# How to Use a Python List as Arguments in a Function

Tags: python, list, function, arguments

If I have a Python list that contains a column of arguments and values, for such as:

```
[('Title','Test'),('Year','1990'),('Date','1/2/1900')]
```

and I want to pass that into a function so that it looks something like this:

```
function('Title' = 'Test', 'Year' = '1990', 'Date' = '1/2/1900')
```

what would be the best way to do that?

Comment: `function(**dict(that_list))`?

Comment: answer above me, assuming you mean `function(Title='Test', Year='1990'...)` because the syntax you used in the question is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the list to a dictionary and pass it to the function.

**Code**

```
x=[('Title','Test'),('Year','1990'),('Date','1/2/1900')]
d = dict(x)

def function(data):
  print(data)
  pass # write whatever you wanna do with your function

function(d)
```

**Output**

```
{'Title': 'Test', 'Year': '1990', 'Date': '1/2/1900'}
```

Comment: That's *not* the same. That's taking a single positional argument, the dictionary itself.

Comment: Actually yes, I updated the answer. What I tried to mean is that this way OP can achieve what he is looking for.

Comment: However, I will add other ways to my answer if I can come up with any. Thanks